# Visual Studio 2022 startup profile selection

Tags: visual-studio-2022

So ... i have **solution with 3 projects**: Server, ClientA and ClientB

clients are connecting to server -> i need to have running server when debugging client so ...

i selected [Solution] -> [Configure Startup Projects ...] and under **Multiple startup projects** i created **2 profiles**:

1. **ProfileA**, that will start Server and ClientA
2. **ProfileB**, that will start Server and ClientB

after that i can see on 'Standard' toolbar '' and debugger will use **ProfileA** profile to start ...

My question is **how to select Launch profile** named ProfileB?

Comment: This isn't a solution but I've had the same struggles. The last-selected multi-start profile isn't run no matter what I do. I've triple-checked the release logs, nothing. I've come to the conclusion this feature is half-baked and not ready yet. It works if you always edit your top-most multi-project config item for now. I think we'll have to wait until the feature is fully ready. I don't know about you, but I've only been waiting 15 years for this feature. So.....close....now. :)